# SQL Server stored procedure call

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure defined in the database and I am trying to call it from the C# server.

In my repository I have a generic method that looks like this:

```
private IList<T> ExecuteReturningProcedure<T>(string procedureName, params ValueTuple<string, object>[] parameters)
        {
            List<T> objList = null;

            ExecuteCommand(procedureName, parameters, CommandType.StoredProcedure, (cmd) =>
            {
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    objList = MapToList<T>(reader).ToList();
                }
            });

            return objList;
        }
```

and I made the specific method for my call that looks like this:

```
public List<dynamic> GetDataSubmissionEntries(Guid dataSubmissionId)
        {
            var parameters = Array.Empty<ValueTuple<string, object>>(); 
            parameters.Append(new ValueTuple<string,object>("@dataSubmissionId", dataSubmissionId));

            var entries = ExecuteReturningProcedure<dynamic>("[DataSubmission].[RetrieveDataSubmissionEntries]", parameters);

            return entries.ToList();
        }
```

The problem is that when the code is executed I get an exception with the message:
Procedure or function 'RetrieveDataSubmissionEntries' expects parameter '@dataSubmissionId', which was not supplied.

Am I contructing the array of parameters the wrong way?

Comment: What is `ExecuteCommand`? can we see that? my initial guess is that it hasn't actually set the `CommandType` (yes, I know I can see it as a parameter, but that doesn't mean that the parameter is used). As a side note: I strongly recommend Dapper for things like this (although disclosure: I'm biased) - it will save you from a lot of subtle and less-subtle errors

Comment: I also recommend Dapper. Disclosure: I'm also biased, but by virtue of liking it rather than being the author. (And having written similar micro-ORM code myself in the past -- I heartily recommend against reinventing the wheel, because doing this well is not trivial.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the parameters for the SP like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd_Sp = new SqlCommand("YourSPname", conn);
cmd_Sp.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd_Sp.Parameters.Add("@dataSubmissionId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataSubmissionId.ToString();
```

Comment: If the parameter's type is known, it's highly recommended to add the size as well (as declared in the procedure), as this prevents pollution of the plan cache and possibly unwanted implicit conversions.

Comment: `SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier` is more likely to be correct here, and the `ToString()` is almost certainly redundant; the only useful part of this is the mention of the `CommandType`, which I already covered in a comment, but; whatever